# Prevent server behaviour : executing scripts without extension

Tags: php, apache2.2

I'm working on a server who has the tendency to execute scripts even when I don't add .php
So lets say my page is activities.php then I can execute my script with :

```
www.example.com/activities.php
www.example.com/activities
and even www.example.com/activities/
```

I've tried to bypass the problem with something like :

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])  header('Location: '. $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

which works fine, well untill I need to post some data.
There is nothing in my htaccess files which explains this behavior (no mod_rewrite stuff or anything). How can I turn this off ?

Server info :

```
Linux Linux1 3.2.0-24-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 21 16:52:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 
Apache Version  Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Apache API Version  20051115
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT :
.htaccess file

```
php_flag display_errors on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_Host} ^domain.be [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.be/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: can you post your .htaccess file?

Comment: Check your apache.conf file extensions settings. It may be set to treat no-extension / default files to be treated as PHP.

Comment: Any chance by doing it with the htaccess file as I can't modify the apache.conf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that your server has [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) (Apache Content Negotiation) enabled; when it is enabled and a file cannot be found apache will look for the same file but with any extension.  To disable this you can add `-MultiViews` to Options (if your host allows it)...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

I would question why this is a problem for you though, if you do not link to any of your scripts without the `.php` then how will people find them?  Canonical URLs are only really an issue if there are links to these other pages.

Additionally, you could improve your php-based redirect to check the current request method and not redirect on POST requests, by inspecting `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`...

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')  header('Location: '. $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Comment: The -MultiViews solved the apache issue indeed. Thanks for that, well the only real problem was when the users started to use the link as /activities/, as I use relative paths for my images and such (ex. <img src="posters/1.jpg" />) the server could not locate these files while being on http://www.domain/activities/

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Glad you got it sorted! :)